# How to access the task status runnning in a button clicking event from the other button clicking event

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I want to know the the task status runnning in A button event from the other button click.
Like this.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Task.Run(()=>{
//The method to take long time
//For example
Thread.Sleep(5000)
;});
}
private coid button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
//until 5000ms
//the method to know the above task status (Runnning....)

//after 5000ms
//the method to know the above task status (Conpleted....)

}
```

Comment: Getting the status of the `Task` is not really the challenge. As you can see from Fayilt's answer, all you need is a reference to the `Task` object. How did you want to handle the use case where `Button1` is clicked multiple times during the execution of the `Task`. Multiple `Task` objects will be created, and the reference is going to be to the last one.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve, but if you want to check the status of the task, you can get its reference when calling Task.Run()

```
private Task _task;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     _task = Task.Run(() => Thread.Sleep(5000));
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (_task?.Status == TaskStatus.RanToCompletion)
        //do something
}
```

The answer is as vague as the question, so if you could give me a bit more details, I could come up with a better more tailored answer.

Answer (score 0):

Again, it's very unclear what you're looking for here...but this is an expanded version of Faylit's example:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private Task T = null;

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateStatus();
    }

    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        button1.Enabled = false;

        await (T = Task.Run(() =>
         {
             updateStatus();
             System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
         }));            

        button1.Enabled = true;
        updateStatus();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        updateStatus();
    }

    private void updateStatus()
    {
        if (label1.InvokeRequired)
        {
            label1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate 
            {
                updateStatus();
            });
        }
        else
        {
            if (T == null)
            {
                label1.Text = "Task not started.";
            }
            else if (!T.IsCompleted)
            {
                label1.Text = "Task running...";
            }
            else
            {
                label1.Text = "Task completed.";
            }
        }            
    }

}
```

It might give you some more ideas.